# Firebase error Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firbade.iid Code = 6

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

recently I switched over to xCode 8 and started using Swift 3. However, now when I build the application I receive a

> failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"

error. This is indeed new and just started happening every since I switched to xCode 8.

Thanks to those who reply, 
Matt

Comment: Any ideas @frankvanpuffelen ?

Answer (score 2):

Is keychain sharing turned on (xCode -> targets -> capabilities)?
This fixed the same problem in my project.